# How to load and plot/screenshot fonts programmatically

Tags: python, image, matlab, scripting

I want to create a dataset of images of symbols (numbers, letters) in different fonts, automatically. I've currently been doing this manually by taking screenshots in a word document. Is there a way to do this programmatically (ideally in Python or MATLAB)?

I know this is a brief question, but I also can't find any helpful starting points on SO or the web.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based off [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-generate-random-text-captchas-using-python-e734dd2d7a51) tutorial:

```
import matplotlib
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image
import numpy as np
import random

#get a list of fonts on the system
system_fonts = matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')

def create_image(text):
  #create blank image object
  size = random.randint(10,16)
  length = random.randint(4,8)
  img = np.zeros(((size*2)+5, length*size, 3), np.uint8)
  img_pil = Image.fromarray(img+255)

  # Drawing text in random font and random color
  font = ImageFont.truetype(random.choice(system_fonts), size)
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)
  draw.text((5, 10), text, font=font, fill=(random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)))

  #save image
  img_pil.save(f"{text}.jpg")
```

You can parse a single text (`create_image('test')`) or generate a list of random strings and loop them.